# elasticsearch network recommendations server linux

Tags: linux-networking, elasticsearch

I am looking for assistance regarding the network settings of my two servers that I am setting up for elasticsearch.
On each server is an embedded network card and a extra network card is install with 4 port, two of which are 10GB.

What I really need is some idea how is best to set the server up network wise for elasticsearch. Bonding yes but how much? 2 ports or all ports together?

Once this is done, I can then install elasticsearch.

Assistance would really be appreciated,

Thanks

Bob

Answer (score 0):

You can of course bond all interfaces together which should enable you to use the combined capacity of those interfaces. You can find a very extensive discussion of linux interface bonding configurations here: https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/bonding .

However I doubt that elasticsearch will be able to drive the full capacity of those interfaces. Elasticsearch is quite demanding on compunting resources. YMMV though.

If you do not mind using up the interfaces of the switch your machine connects to then bonding all interfaces together shouldn't do much harm (other than using more electricity...).

Comment: So was my answer correct? Wrong? Useful? Useless? Can you mark it then as such please?